# SHA-256 different values in Java and vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, sha256

Starting over isn't an option because an already running project uses SHA-256

Here's the java code  --->>> just a simple code to hash any string

```
    public static String SHA256 (String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,    UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-8");  
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
textByte = md.digest(textByte);
return Base64.encodeToString(textByte,Base64.NO_CLOSE);
}
```

and the VB code as follows

```
 Public Function EncryptPassword(ByVal password As String) As String
        Dim hashedPassword As String = Nothing
        Dim hashProvider As SHA256Managed = Nothing
        Try
            Dim passwordBytes() As Byte
            passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)
            hashProvider = New SHA256Managed
            hashProvider.Initialize()
            passwordBytes = hashProvider.ComputeHash(passwordBytes)
            hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordBytes)
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            If Not hashProvider Is Nothing Then
                hashProvider.Clear()
                hashProvider = Nothing
            End If
        End Try
        Return hashedPassword
    End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your problem, but 'byte' in Java is signed, so it is equivalent to 'SByte' in VB, not 'Byte'.

Answer (score 2):

Well it might not be the only problem but System.Text.Encoding.Unicode in VB is UTF-16LE where as your Java code is using UTF-8.

Comment: THANKS A LOT Aestel! IT WORKS NOW! for anyone who had the same bugging issue... change 

textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-8");


TO

 textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-16LE");